# Is there a way to define implicit pointer to pointer conversions?

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have this struct

```
struct wrap256_t {
    alignas(32) uint64_t u64[4];
    wrap256_t(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c, uint64_t d) : u64{ a, b, c, d } {}
    wrap256_t() {}
};
```

I know I could just use the __m256i type but this works out nicer with me being able to initialize it easily to consts and references and whatnot, I don't need speed for initializing the starting data. Deeper in the code however, I like to use it with AVX2 intrinsics such as _mm256_load_si256 or _mm256_store_si256. I don't like typing reinterpret_cast whenever I load or store data into registers however.

Since the intrinsics I'm interested in all expect __m256i* as the source type and since these wrappers are mostly allocated in the heap either individually or as arrays with new, I figured it would be really nice if I could define an implicit conversion from wrap256_t* to __m256i*. Is that something I can do and how do I do that?

I know that I can define a conversion from wrap256_t to __m256i* but that just feels weird, I want to convert pointer to pointer instead.

Comment: Nope. (This space intentionally left blank)

Comment: The fact that you have to (or *should* have to) make the effort of typing out the long text of `reinterpret_cast<boo*>(&far)` whenever you convert between pointers to **unrelated types** is a good thing. Rather than looking for a shorthand way to do this, you should be looking at ways to minimize the use of such casts. Otherwise, *there be dragons*.

Comment: Why not use __m256i internally? You can still have a nice constructor just like now.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot influence the possible implicit conversions between raw pointers.

You *could* do some trickery with operator overloading to make it seem like there was this implicit conversion until someone actually specifies the raw pointer type.

Specifically you could overload the address-of operator to return a wrapped pointer instead of a raw one and then have that wrapper class define conversion functions to the underlying raw pointer type and to `__m256i*`.

Whether this is a good idea is a different question...